# Twitter pixel activating multiple times - error with pixel helper or page?

Tags: html, twitter, pixel

I am seeing an issue alerted from my Twitter pixel helper extension that website tags are activating multiple times on a web page, but I can't work out why.

I am not a developer - I work in social media - but installing the odd tracking code is part of my role. I have taken out the actual codes in the below script.

If anyone else has experience this I would be interested to hear about their solutions! Thanks!

```
<!-- Twitter conversion tracking base code -->
<script>
!function(e,t,n,s,u,a){e.twq||(s=e.twq=function(){s.exe?s.exe.apply(s,arguments):s.queue.push(arguments);
},s.version='1.1',s.queue=[],u=t.createElement(n),u.async=!0,u.src='https://static.ads-twitter.com/uwt.js',
a=t.getElementsByTagName(n)[0],a.parentNode.insertBefore(u,a))}(window,document,'script');
twq('config','BASECODE');
</script>
<!-- End Twitter conversion tracking base code -->
<!-- Twitter conversion tracking event code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Insert Twitter Event ID
  twq('event', 'BASECODE+EVENT', {
  });
</script>
<!-- End Twitter conversion tracking event code -->
<!-- Twitter conversion tracking event code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Insert Twitter Event ID
  twq('event', 'BASECODE+EVENT', {
  });
</script>
<!-- End Twitter conversion tracking event code -->
```

We aren't running ads at the moment so it's hard to test, but have had issues in the past with leads not being recorded when I had the event and base codes bundled together (ie all codes were in the same parameter). As an alternative I have separated them out - as above. But the Pixel code error remains the same.

Comment: I am hitting this same issue in a Next.js-based project. I have the base code set up in the Document layout, and am manually calling the `twq('event', ...)` on a button click. As far as I can tell (via a bunch of console logs and by digging through dev tools), nothing is happening more than once.